# Object axis rotation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

When I rotate an object in OpenGL, the axis also rotates with the object. Is there a way to avoid this? Basically, I want to achieve the successive rotations around the same axis.

I am not very familiar with quaternions but as I read it, it seems to be a solution. Is there any other way to get it?

Comment: can you show your code with part of multiplying matrices?

Comment: I store the previous transformation using glGetDoublev and then before applying the new rotation, I load that matrix by glLoad and then multiply it with the new rotation matrix. In my application, I have to serialize the object on disk, thats why I did it this way. Along with the object, I store the transformation matrix as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I rotate an object in OpenGL, the axis also rotates with the object.

The transformation does not rotate the object, it rotates the coordinate system. Chaining rotations is noncommutative. So what you must do is simply: Swap the rotation operations, that the first rotation applied, i.e. the last you multiply on the stack designates your object rotation, followed (i.e. previously multiplied) with the other rotation.

BTW: In a comment you wrote:

> I store the previous transformation using glGetDoublev and then before applying the new rotation, I load that matrix by glLoad and then multiply it with the new rotation matrix. In my application, I have to serialize the object on disk, thats why I did it this way. Along with the object, I store the transformation matrix as well

This suggests you've mistaken OpenGL for a scene graph or a matrix math library. It is neither. Don't use OpenGL as an "object store" (it doesn't work like this), and don't rely on OpenGL's matrix functions (they got removed from OpenGL-3 anyway).

Comment: I considered openGL for fast prototyping, but I actually dont need it since I use it only for matrix manipulation and I know openGL is not for this. Could you please suggest a library which can do this for me? I want to transform object not the axis.

Comment: @Aarkan: Matrix math isn't very complicated. You can implement it yourself, or use a library like http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/ or LAPACK. For working with triangulated geometry there's http://gts.sourceforge.net/ If you really just want to do 4x4 matrix math I provide https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h which is in the public domain.

Comment: Thanks, just one doubt. If I use glm for example, and I apply matrices R1 and R2 for two rotations on object M, i.e. if I carry out this: R2*R1*M then will R2 still operate on rotated axis caused by rotation R1?

Comment: @Aarkan: Well yes. You must understand, that multiplying matrices generates a compound transform. It's best to think about the individual steps happening to each vertex v of M: First v is rotated by R1, yielding v', then v' is rotated by R2 to v''